# OData how to filter child collection and return only items with condition

Tags: json, filter, odata

I have been struggling with returning items from a collection that have a certain condition.

With the any call I receive 3/3 items in the collection while 1/3 has met the condition.

With the all call I receive 0/3 items in the collection while 1/3 has met the condition.

I want to receive only the item from the collection that has met the condition, so 1/3 in the example.

Here's my filter:

```
&$filter=OrderRules/all(o: o/Product/Name eq 'Geportioneerd Vlees')
```

I probably misunderstand the use of any/all, but I am out of ideas for reaching my goal.

Here's the collection of the 3 items:

```
[
  {
    "Oid": "6b62a0bf-82ac-43e9-be93-12921d118f61",
    "DateDurability": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "DateFreezing": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "DateProduction": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "Finished": false,
    "Colli": 10,
    "Note": null,
    "PricePerColli": 0,
    "TotalPrice": 0,
    "UnitsGross": 10,
    "Unit": {
      "Oid": "675f4370-14f9-4610-9d61-7cafb560aca7",
      "Name": "Kilogram",
      "Symbol": "kg"
    },
    "Product": {
      "Oid": "5424ca76-dc76-4662-8490-8729d6a45c9d",
      "Description": null,
      "Name": "Kreeft 600-700"
    },
    "DeliveryRules": [
      {
        "Oid": "fc052ab9-a69f-4678-a5ef-42b6d981dc67",
        "TraceCode": null,
        "Finished": false,
        "Colli": 1,
        "UnitsGross": 12
      }
    ],
    "Package": null
  },
  {
    "Oid": "902cbe06-7484-4568-b505-76fe42c5096a",
    "DateDurability": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "DateFreezing": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "DateProduction": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "Finished": false,
    "Colli": 68,
    "Note": null,
    "PricePerColli": 88.9,
    "TotalPrice": 6045.2,
    "UnitsGross": 680,
    "Unit": {
      "Oid": "675f4370-14f9-4610-9d61-7cafb560aca7",
      "Name": "Kilogram",
      "Symbol": "kg"
    },
    "Product": {
      "Oid": "873aa84b-7a2a-440c-9f04-1a620fc081f4",
      "Description": null,
      "Name": "Geportioneerd Vlees"
    },
    "DeliveryRules": [
      {
        "Oid": "4b250474-4f32-438e-b6c0-94cb5d4bdffe",
        "TraceCode": null,
        "Finished": false,
        "Colli": 1,
        "UnitsGross": 100
      }
    ],
    "Package": {
      "Oid": "a51654e4-28fd-410f-8b39-fda4e884b5c1",
      "Name": "Doos 10x1kg"
    }
  },
  {
    "Oid": "356238af-9be3-412e-82cb-ae9e5ec3997b",
    "DateDurability": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "DateFreezing": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "DateProduction": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "Finished": false,
    "Colli": 52,
    "Note": null,
    "PricePerColli": 0,
    "TotalPrice": 0,
    "UnitsGross": 52,
    "Unit": null,
    "Product": {
      "Oid": "ce56132a-c152-4fd1-a5de-6b1a7290053f",
      "Description": null,
      "Name": "Gerookte zalmzijde gesneden"
    },
    "DeliveryRules": [],
    "Package": null
  }
]
```